# Two random variables and probability using normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence

I'm trying to prep myself for entrance exams and struggle with the following problem:

Mr. X uses two buses daily on his journey to work. Bus A departs 6.00 and Mr. X always catches that. The journey time follows normal distribution $(24, 4^2)$. Bus B departs at 6.20, 6.30 and 6.40, journey time following normal distribution $(20, 5^2)$, independent of bus A. We assume the transfer from bus A to B won't take time and Mr. X always takes the first bus B available. Calculate probability for Mr. X being at work before 6.55.

So I am aware that the sum of two normal distribution variables follows also normal distribution, but don't know how two proceed with the given departure times of bus B (6.20, 6.30, 6.40) as clearly I can't just calculate the probability of A+B being under 55 minutes.. Any tips how to start with this?

Comment: The sum of the random variables is irrelevant.  That would give the time he spends on the bus, but we only care when he arrives at the office.  The total trip time includes time spent waiting for bus $B$.  You need to start by calculating the probabilities that he takes each of the $3$ possible B buses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some **hints**:

Let's $A$ and $B$ denote the times bus A and B take. So, we have
$A \sim N(24,16)$ and $B\sim N(20,25)$.

There are three disjoint cases, how a time below $55\; min$ can be reached:

- $A\leq 20 \cap B<35$
- $20<A\leq 30 \cap B<25$
- $30<A\leq 40 \cap B<15$

Now, use addition rule for probabilities and independence of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: This was actually what I tried at first, resulting to a probability over 1 which lead me to abandon this method. However, now I notice that my mistake was not to include the lower limit to options 2 and 3 - I just used upper limits A < 30 and A < 40. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @fochsia You are welcome. My pleasure to help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$P(\text{at work before 6:55}) = \sum_{k\in \{ A,B,C\}} P(\text{bus}_k) P(\text{on time}| \text{bus}_k).$$